# OpenCV, Dlib - Mat object outputed as black image

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, mat, dlib

I have 4 channel Mat object.
I'm trying(as part of a process), to convert it to `dlib` data(make some changes), and back to `Mat`.

For some reason, the final output is complete black. I'm trying to be as much **efficient in terms of runtime.**

```
cv::Mat image;
cv::cvtColor(image, image, CV_RGBA2BGR); //convert to 3 channels
//COPY pointer saves runtime
dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel> dlibimg;
dlib::assign_image(dlibimg, dlib::cv_image<dlib::bgr_pixel>(cvimg));
image = dlib::toMat(dlibimg); //black
```

**Any suggestions, why the output is complete black?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel> dlibimg` should be

```
`dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_alpha_pixel> dlibimg`
```

as you have given 4 channel Mat image.